# Google Script - trying to design a sheet with a running total but don't know how to getValue of contents of previous row same column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am transferring data from a (shUser)form to a new (blank)row in a datasheet.
I want to add a running total at the end col. of the row ie into col. 12 of the blankRow. After adding number from shUserForm("E17")-(received)-, subtract the number from shUserform("E15")- paid out-  and adding to previous running total from datasheet lastRow col.12.

scripts so far -

```
function submitData(){
 
  var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("TRANSACTIONS");

  var shAccount=shUserForm.getRange("E5").getValue();

  var datasheet=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName(shAccount);

  var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1;

  //code to update the data in datasheet

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E5").getValue()); 

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E7").getValue());

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E9").getValue());

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E11").getValue());

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E13").getValue());

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("E19").getValue());

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,12).setFormula???XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
```

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to do is to setFormula("=SUM(()") It hard to figure what the exact formula is because your explanation is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample script of how I would do it.  Notice I make every effort to combine calls to the server.  Rather than a bunch of `getValue()/setValue()` I use `getValues()/setValues()` as much as possible.  For example, in your script you are getting numerous values from column E.  I simply get a 2D array of E using `getValues()` and then remember which index into that array corresponds to the row.  Similar to your `setValue()`.  You are placing values in consecutive columns of the new row.  I simply construct a 1D array of that row and then use `setValues([dataSheetValues])` to place a 2D array in that row at the proper location.

Because your `shUserForm` values are changing based on account I would think you wouldn't want to have a bunch of formulas in `datasheet` link to that sheet, but I have shown how to build the formula in case that is your intention.  I've also shown how to calculate the value but have commented it out.

It is also my practice to always enclose my code in a `try{} catch(){}` block.

**Code.gs**

```
function submitData(){
  try {
    let myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("TRANSACTIONS");
    let shAccount=shUserForm.getRange("E5").getValue();
    let datasheet=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName(shAccount);
    let blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1;
    let shUserFormValues = shUserForm.getRange(5,5,15,1).getValues();
    let dataSheetValues = [];  // [[E5],[E7],[E9],[E11],[E13],[E19]
    for( let i=0; i<9; i+=2 ) {
      dataSheetValues.push(shUserFormValues[i][0]); // E5 to E13
    }
    dataSheetValues.push(shUserFormValues[14][0]); // E19

    //code to update the data in datasheet

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,2,1,6).setValues([dataSheetValues]);

    // to perform the running total

    // If you only want the value
    // let previousValue = dataSheet.getRange(blankRow-1,12).getValue();
    // let runningTotal = previousValue+shUserFormValues[12][0]-shUserFormValues[10][0];
    // datasheet.getRange(blankRow,12).setValue(runningTotal);

    // If you prefer a formula
    let sumFormula = "="+shAccount+"!L"+(blankRow-1)+"+TRANSACTIONS!E17-TRANSACTIONS!E15";
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,12).setFormula(sumFormula);

  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Reference**

- [Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)
- [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Range.setFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)
- [Array.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)
- [Error handling](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

Comment: Great, worked 'straight out of the tin' Thank you.